# How can I do something similar to VLOOKUP in Excel with urlparse?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to compare two sets of data from csv's, one (csv1) with a column 'listing_url' the other (csv2) with columns 'parsed_url' and 'url_code'. I would like to use the result set from urlparse on csv1 (specifically the netloc) to compare to csv2 'parsed_url' and output matching value from 'url_code' to csv.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import re, pandas as pd
scr = pd.read_csv('csv2',squeeze=True,usecols=['parsed_url','url_code'])[['parsed_url','url_code']]
data = pd.read_csv('csv1')
L = data.values.T[0].tolist()
T = pd.Series([scr])
for i in L:
    n = urlparse(i)
    nf = pd.Series([(n.netloc)])
```

I'm stuck trying to convert the data into objects I can use `map` with, if that's even the best thing to use, I don't know.